# app keystore and certs in phone storage?

Tags: certificates

is there method to view and export files from phone storage keystore?

the android app i got has the keystore to managed digital user certs, it can be viewed via UI, i wanted to view them in phone storage but could not locate them.

Comment: Please be specific. Android has several "keystore" systems. Are you referring to the AndroidKeystore? This on modern devices a hardware protected storage for certificate and private keys. Which app are you  talking about?

Comment: @Robert the app that developer design encrypted the user and CA certs in 'Keystore'. I thought it should be visible in app location but i did not see any file. so I wondering what other method to view it.

Comment: Decompile the app and search for `AndroidKeystore`. It it uses this keystore type and you are on a recent device then the private keys are stored hardware protected. The keys can only be used on the device but not extracted. The AndroidKeystore is a system service that stores all keys+certs of all apps on the system.

Comment: @Robert i have the apk file only. can i decompile it? i did not own the source codes.

Comment: Decompile it e.g. using [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) and search for the term `AndroidKeystore`.